# jQuery - set cart values to 0 in two locations

Tags: jquery, shopping-cart

I'm working on a shopping cart with some advanced jQuery functionality. I've got everything working except for the remove item from cart button that appears next to the item in the cart. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to target the value on the left side of the page that need to change back to 0.

I've made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/richcoy/GpUWn/

If you press an up button to add an item to the cart you will see it appear in the cart. Next to the item is an X button to remove it from the cart. When that button is clicked it needs to set both the value in the cart and the value next to the up button back to zero.

I know the close.click function at the end of the JS fires but can't figure out what goes into it to zero out the value on the left.

**HTML**

```
<div id="body_container">

<div id="product_container">
    <div class="product_box">
        <div class="item_name">Item One</div>   
        <div class="product">0</div>
        <button class="up category_one_up">Up</button>
        <button class="down category_one_down">Down</button>
    </div>

    <div class="product_box">
        <div class="item_name">Item Two</div>   
        <div class="product">0</div>
        <button class="up category_one_up">Up</button>
        <button class="down category_one_down">Down</button>
    </div>

    <div class="product_box">
        <div class="item_name">Item Three</div>    
        <div class="product">0</div>
        <button class="up category_one_up">Up</button>
        <button class="down category_one_down">Down</button>
    </div>

    <div class="product_box">
        <div class="item_name">Item Four</div>
        <div class="product">0</div>
        <button class="up category_two_up">Up</button>
        <button class="down category_two_down">Down</button>
    </div>

    <div class="product_box">
        <div class="item_name">Item Five</div>       
        <div class="product">0</div>
        <button class="up category_three_up">Up</button>
        <button class="down category_three_down">Down</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="cart_container">
    <h3>Shopping Cart</h3>
    <div class="catone_header"><h3>Category One</h3></div>
        <div class="cart_product">
            <div class="item_name">Item One</div>
            <input type="text" class="cart_product_number" value="0" />
            <button class="close">X</button>
        </div>
        <div class="cart_product">
            <div class="item_name">Item Two</div>
            <input type="text" class="cart_product_number" value="0" />
            <button class="close">X</button>
        </div>
        <div class="cart_product">
            <div class="item_name">Item Three</div>
            <input type="text" class="cart_product_number" value="0" />
            <button class="close">X</button>
        </div>
        <div class="cattwo_header"><h3>Category Two</h3></div>
        <div class="cart_product">
            <div class="item_name">Item Four</div>
            <input type="text" class="cart_product_number" value="0" />
            <button class="close">X</button>
        </div>
        <div class="catthree_header"><h3>Category Three</h3></div>
        <div class="cart_product">
            <div class="item_name">Item Five</div>
            <input type="text" class="cart_product_number" value="0" />
            <button class="close">X</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end #body_container -->
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var num;
    var catone = 0;
    var cattwo = 0;
    var catthree = 0;

$('.up').click(function() {
    num = parseInt($(this).siblings('.product').text());
    console.log(num);
    $(this).prevAll('.product').text(num + 1);
    $('.cart_product').eq($(this).closest('.product_box').index()).fadeIn('slow').find('.cart_product_number').val(num + 1);
});

$('.down').click(function() {
    num = parseInt($(this).siblings('.product').text());
    if (num > 0) {
        $(this).siblings('.product').text(num - 1);
    };

    if (parseInt($(this).siblings('.product').text()) === 0) {
        $('.cart_product').eq($(this).closest('.product_box').index()).fadeOut('slow');
    } else {
        $('.cart_product').eq($(this).closest('.product_box').index()).show().find('.cart_product_number').val(num - 1);
    }
});


// Category One
$('.category_one_up').click(function() {
    catone++;
    if (catone > 0) {
        $('.catone_header').fadeIn('slow');
    };
});

$('.category_one_down').click(function() {
    if (catone > 0) {
        catone--;

        if (catone <= 0) {
            $('.catone_header').fadeOut('slow');
        };
    };
});

// Category Two
$('.category_two_up').click(function() {
    cattwo++;
    if (cattwo > 0) {
        $('.cattwo_header').fadeIn('slow');
    };
});

$('.category_two_down').click(function() {
    if (cattwo > 0) {
        cattwo--;

        if (cattwo <= 0) {
            $('.cattwo_header').fadeOut('slow');
        };
    };
});

// Category Three
$('.category_three_up').click(function() {
    catthree++;
    if (catthree > 0) {
        $('.catthree_header').fadeIn('slow');
    };
});

$('.category_three_down').click(function() {
    if (catthree > 0) {
        catthree--;

        if (catthree <= 0) {
            $('.catthree_header').fadeOut('slow');
        };
    };
});

$('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('div.cart_product').fadeOut('slow');
    $(this).prev('.cart_product_number').val(0);
});


});
```

Comment: I don't think you are on the right track here. You can probably fix this code to get it working, but my main concern is that you don't have a model behind your UI. You're making maintenance more difficult and changing or adding something in the future will be difficult.

My suggestion would be to create a shopping cart object that maintains the state of the shopping card and notifies the rest of the UI to update itself when a product is added or removed.

Comment: The code is easy to understand, which is vital in Javascript. If something needs to be added in the future then re-factoring isn't going to be too mind-numbingly difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you've placed a reference on your products to target them directly, but an adjustment to your code would be:

See this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/GpUWn/5/) example.

```
$('.close').click(function() {

   // get the name of the item
   var myProd = $(this).closest('div').find('.item_name').html();

   // find it on the left list
   $target = $('#product_container').find('.item_name').filter(function() {
     return $(this).html().match(myProd);
   });

   // reset to 0        
   $target.next().html('0');

   // your code...
   $(this).parent('div.cart_product').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This will get the job done. This client only has 15 products and could not be talked into a prebuilt cart system.

Comment: @RichCoy Check my edit for a more secure solution... instead of `:contains()`, I'm suggesting `.match()` to prevent collision with products with similar names.

Comment: My only problem now is that by clicking the X the count of products is wrong and the category headings in the cart are still there. Ugh. I knew I was hacking that feature together, need to rethink that.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that `id` attribute is understood to be unique.

Next, as for XHTML standard, afaik, you could define your own tag attributes. So, you could pass the element you want to set to zero, for example, as an attribute for each *close* button:

```
<button class="close" moo="product_item_1">X</button>
```

Here, the `moo` attribute defines which container contains the value that should be reset. Then you just get the value of that attribute for the button clicked, form the element selector, get the element and reset its HTML:

```
// format the ID selector
var item_id = '#' + $(this).attr('moo');
// format the concrete "input" selector, you need to reset
// and reset its HTML
jQuery(item_id + ' .product').html('0');
```

Here's how it is done: http://jsfiddle.net/j99Cv/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the repeated id's. They were not needed anyway and have been removed.